# Autoencoder Gridsearch Hyperparameter tuning Keras

Tags: python, keras, grid-search

My data shape is the same, I just generated here random numbers. In real the datas are float numbers from  range -6 to 6, I scaled them as well. The Input layer size and Encoding dimension have to remain the same. When I am training the loss starts and stays at `0.631` all the time. I changed the learning rate manually. I am new to python and do not know to implement to a grid search to this code to find the right parameters. What else can I do to tune my network ?

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras import optimizers

#Train data
x_train=np.random.rand(2666000)
x_train = (train-min(train))/(max(train)-min(train))
x_train=x_train.reshape(-1,2000)

x_test=[]#empty testing later
#Enc Dimension 
encoding_dim=100
#Input shape
input_dim = Input(shape=(2000,))
#Encoding Layer
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(input_dim)
#Decoding Layer
decoded = Dense(2000, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)

#Model AE
autoencoder = Model(input_dim, decoded)
#Model Encoder 
encoder = Model(input_dim, encoded)
#Encoding
encoded_input = Input(shape=(encoding_dim,))
#Decoding 
decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]
#Model Decoder 
decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer(encoded_input))

optimizers.Adadelta(lr=0.1, rho=0.95, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', 
                metrics=['accuracy'])
#Train and test 
autoencoder_train= autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
            epochs=epochs, shuffle=False, batch_size=2048)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest adding more hidden layers. If your loss stays the same it means at least one of two things:

- Your data is more or less random and there are no relationships to be drawn
- Your model is not complex enough to learn meaningful relationships from your data

A rule of thumb for me is that a model should be powerful enough to overfit the data given enough training iterations.

Unfortunately there is a fine line between sufficiently complex and too complex. You have to play around with the number of hidden layers, the number of units in each layer, and the amount of epochs you take to train your network. Since you only have two Dense layers, a good starting point would be to increase model complexity.

[image]

If you insist on using a grid search keras has a wrapper for scikit_learn and sklearn has a grid search module. A toy example:

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

def create_model():
    <return a compiled but untrained keras model>

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn = create_model, batch_size=1000, epochs=10)
#now write out all the parameters you want to try out for the grid search
activation = ['relu', 'tanh', 'sigmoid'...]
learn_rate = [0.1, 0.2, ...]
init = ['unform', 'normal', 'zero', ...]
optimizer = ['SGD', 'Adam' ...]
param_grid = dict(activation=activation, learn_rate=learn_rate, init=init, optimizer=optimizer)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid)
result = grid.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: Your decoded has 2000 units, while encoded only has 100. If you reduced the width of your model you can certainly make use of more layers without a big impact on performance

Comment: A second point is try compiling your model with optimizer='adam'

Comment: I know that maybe you are right, because I just was testing the model on a standard computer and wanted to go to later with inputlayer:2000- hidden layer:1000, outputlayer: 2000. Besides these hints, still how can I implement grid search into my code ? @Primusa

Comment: @pynewb If you have restricted calculation power why are you trying a grid search?

Comment: its just for getting myself better in this topic. I want to understand it.